# MAPI for out of office Rules

Tags: .net, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I need to read and modify "out of office" rules (not subject, body or enabled flag) using MAPI, or any other API if possible, for example I need to read to whom the mails should be forwarded and to modify this field. Do you know any samples, url, starting point or anything else what could help me achive this

thanks
almir

Comment: I forgot to mention, I need to call it from .NET

Comment: Then unless EWS supports it, which I'm not sure it does, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view and change the Out Of Office rule.  There is a KB article which shows an example of creating an OOF rule, so it shouldn't be too hard to modify it for your needs.  It's a few years old, but the process hasn't changed.

[How to create an Out-Of-Office rule with Extended MAPI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308281)

Comment: I am currently trying to implement is as com componente which is described in this article but I can not find edk.h files